# Angular ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (usining password: NO)

Tags: mysql, angular

I work on Angular Project and trying to connect mysql Database using npx sequelize db:migrate

but run command after some error (Angular ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (usining password: NO))

Database and password is perfect my `.env` and  `config.js` file

config.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
moduleexports ={
    "development": {
        "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
        "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "test":{
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "database_test",
        "host": 127.0.0.1,
        "dialect": "mysql"
    }
    
    "production":{
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "database_producting",
        "host": 127.0.0.1,
        "dialect": "mysql"
    }
}
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=banner_automation
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: you are using local host the database is on the same server that your project ? and  could you post the code  that you are  using to connect to the database, it might help us understand better your problem. and another point try to connect to the database  using some database management app as mysqladmin and so on with your same credentials to check if its ok.

Comment: mysqldatabase is xampp folder and my angular code is another folder and phpmyadmin path is ```localhost:8080/phpmyadmin``` server name is ```localhost``` and angiular path is ```localhost:3000```

Comment: ok it seems to be in the same server anyway, but as the error says you are trying to login in with a non password user and it seems to not be allowed, are  you able to create a new user to connect to your DB? if yes I seguess to create it with password and chenge it on your code

Comment: this link might be helpfull https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html#:~:text=Creating%20a%20new%20user,user%20to%20your%20particular%20needs.